# couldn't execute "mysql": no such file or directory, using autoexpect

Tags: bash-scripting, expect

I have the following file: exp.exp

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

db_host='localhost'
db_name='webui_dev'
db_user='root'
db_pass='rootpass'
new_db_name='db_2011'

expect <<EOF
  log_user 0
  spawn mysql -h $db_host -u $db_user -p $db_pass 'create database $new_db_name'
  expect "password:"
  send "$db_pass\r"
  log_user 1
  expect eof
EOF
```

I make it executable by `sudo chmod +x script/year_changer/create_db.exp`, but if I try to execute it I get an error:

```
couldn't execute "mysql": no such file or directory
    while executing
"spawn mysql -h localhost  -u root -p rootpass  'create database db_2011'"
```

Comment: I have to ask the obvious... Is the mysql client installed?

Comment: Yes definitely. `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server restart
Shutting down MySQL
.. SUCCESS! 
Starting MySQL
.... SUCCESS! `

Comment: Is the `mysql` command in your `$PATH` when you run the script?

Comment: @Barmar. Don't know really. How can I check it??

Comment: What happens if you just type `mysql` from the shell instead of running the script?

Comment: `echo $PATH` and see if it contains the directory where the `mysql` executable is installed?

Comment: what does "which mysql" say? it might be that mysql is not in your path?

Comment: That's the MySQL *server* I asked about the *client*.

Comment: I'm sorry.. It's my mistake `mysql
-bash: mysql: command not found`

Comment: BTW, since you're specifying the password on the command line, it won't prompt for the password, so you shouldn't `expect "password:"`.

Comment: @Barmar. May you post you answer as an Answer?

Comment: I didn't give an answer, I just asked questions, what should I post?

Comment: @Journeyman Geek It's blank, but you are right, it isn't in my path. By typing mysql I reseive an error `mysql
-bash: mysql: command not found`. So I need to add it to the path.

Comment: hm, which should normally give a full path, IIRC, is it even installed?

Comment: Yes it is. I added mysql commans to my path and it works.

Comment: @Barmar. But your question was an clue to the solution. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Giving a command, without a full path, only really works without a path to the executable if its in your path variables - [as per the mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/setting-environment-variables.html), you need to add `PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin` to your path - in .bashrc for interactive shells or .bash_profiles for non interactive ones.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your mysql binary is in your $PATH variable. You can check this by executing

```
echo $PATH;
```

If you do not see the path to your mysql binary there, you'll have to modify the PATH variable and add the path to your mysql binary in the ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_rc file to make it available globally on login

You can alternatively use the full path to your mysql binary in your code. For example

```
spawn /usr/bin/mysql -h $db_host -u $db_user -p $db_pass 'create database $new_db_name'
```